# convert matrix to cell string with elements separated by delimiter

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, cells

How can I convert a matrix

```
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6]
```

to a cell of string

```
A_str = {'1_2_3';'4_5_6'};
```

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer (don't edit the question) when you are allowed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be this -

```
%// Input
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6] 

%// Make a cell array with each element a string off each element of A
cells = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),num2cell(A),'Uni',0)

%// Join the cells with strjoin using `_` as the delimiter 
A_str = arrayfun(@(n) strjoin(cells(n,:),'_'),1:size(cells,1),'Uni',0).'
```

Output -

```
A_str = 
    '1_2_3'
    '4_5_6'
```

Answer (score 1):

found this solution that seems faster

```
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6] 

A_str = cell(size(A,1),1);
for index_row = 1 : size(A,1)
    clear allOneString_temp
    allOneString_temp = sprintf('%.0f_' , A(index_row,:));
    A_str{index_row,:} = allOneString_temp(1:end-1);
end
```

Comment: Are those only single digit numbers in `A` in your actual case?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, without loops:

```
A_str = num2str(A,'%i_');
A_str = mat2cell(A_str(:,1:end-1), ones(1,size(A_str,1)));
```